# Android Background Email task not sending, causing error

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

So i've set up a task that sends an email in the background using the javax.mail api and i'm getting an error in the stacktrace causing the email not to send.
Ive Annotated the specifc lines that throw the error with a comment `/*............*/`

stack trace.

```
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ nested exception is:
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: smtp.gmail.com
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1389)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.AlarmReceiver$SendMailTask.doInBackground(AlarmReceiver.java:96)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.AlarmReceiver$SendMailTask.doInBackground(AlarmReceiver.java:80)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-22 16:34:47.052  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
08-22 16:34:47.062  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: smtp.gmail.com
08-22 16:34:47.062  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:856)
08-22 16:34:47.062  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:816)
08-22 16:34:47.062  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
08-22 16:34:47.062  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
08-22 16:34:47.062  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
08-22 16:34:47.062  20025-20422/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
```

Broadcast Receiver code:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        public AlarmReceiver() {
        }
        Context cont;
        public String DATAOUT() {
            String Dataout = "";
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new
                        File(cont.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "XXXXXXXXXX.txt")));
                String read;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

                while ((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(read);
                }
                Log.d("Output", builder.toString());
                Dataout = builder.toString();
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return Dataout;
        }

        private Session createSessionObject() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

            return Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("XXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX1298");
                }
            });
        }

        private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, Session session) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com", "Admin"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, email));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(messageBody);
            return message;
        }




/*Line 80 (error)*/        private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }

            @Override
 /*Line 96 (error)*/           protected Void doInBackground(Message... messages) {
                try {
                    Transport.send(messages[0]);
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void sendMail(String email, String subject, String messageBody) {
            Session session = createSessionObject();
            try {
                Message message = createMessage(email, subject, messageBody, session);
                new SendMailTask().execute(message);
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String check = "";
            String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            File checker = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "LEGION_LOCATION_DATA.txt");
            if(checker.exists()) {
                sendMail("XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXXXX.com", "DataTest", DATAOUT());
                Log.d("Update", "Update Sent");
                check = "Auto Check In Complete At " + currentDateTimeString;
            }
            else
            {
                check = "ERROR";
                sendMail("XXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXXX.com", "DataTest",check);
            }

            Intent intenti= new Intent(context, Locator.class);
            intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intenti, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.legionnotifyicon)
                            .setContentTitle("Legion Link")
                            .setContentText(check);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: `Host is unresolved: smtp.gmail.com` it seems that you don't have internet connection (or permission ?)